# Cropping An Image while maintaining the coordinates in python

Tags: python

I have a 5120 X 5120 tif image, and I want to crop it to 25 small images of 1024 X 1024. How can I do it while maintaining the image coordinates of 5120 X 5120 tif image into my small cropped images using python?
How can I incorporate the coordinate info of the original image into my cropped images, so I get the same coordinates when checking them in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

So first (if you haven't) you need to install **Pillow**. You can do that by opening **Command Prompt** and typing in:

> pip install pillow

Now type this code into your Python script.

```
from PIL import Image

image = "test.png"
tiles = 5

original_img = Image.open(image)

width, height = original_img.size

w = width / tiles
h = height / tiles

for x in range(tiles):
    for y in range(tiles):

        cropped = original_img.crop((w * x, h * y, w * x + w, h * y + h))
        cropped.save("(" + str(int(w * x)) + ", " + str(int(h * y)) + "), (" + str(int(w * x + w)) + ", " + str(int(h * y + h)) + ").png")

print("Done!")
```

So the "image" variable is your image name or path to it.
You can change the "tiles" variable to change how many tiles are made on the x-axis and y-axis.
Your cropped images will be saved in your script's folder.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is great that I can get the cropped images. However, the cropped images lost all of the coordinate info. I checked it on QGIS, and I noticed that the cropped images no longer have the coordinate info that the original image (5120 x 5120) had. How can I incorporate the coordinate info of the original image into my cropped images?

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't really understand what you wanted with coordinate info, I still don't quite understand but I changed something so now image names are coordinates from where to where was image cut from the original image.

Comment: Thank you very much! What I mean by the coordinates is the geographical location of the image. When I open the original image (the one with 5120 x 5120) in QGIS, the left top corner has the coordinates (676504, 4166992), so I want the first cropped image (0_0.tif) to also have the same coordinates. In QGIS every point in an image has a specific coordinates, so I want those coordinates to be maintained on my cropped images. Basically, I want the metadata of the original image to be maintained on my cropped images. I am not sure if it can be done by Pillow. I guess it can be done by rasterio.